# How to convert JsonNode to String without escaping quote - with \" instead of "

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following class. I use `ObjectMapper.convertValue()` to convert this class to Jackson ObjectNode. Then `ObjectNode.toString()` will return a String like `"{"playing": false}"`.

But what I am looking for is the Json String without escaping quote like `"{\"playing\": false}"`.

I am currently using `String.replace("\"", "\\\"")`, and it worked. Is there any better way to achieve that?

**Update Node:** As mentioned in the comment, I need to send this state String to server, but it looks like my server can only recognize `"{\"playing\": false}"`.

```
public class MyState {
    public Boolean playing;
}

private String getStateString()
throws Exception
{
    ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.convertValue(currentState, ObjectNode.class);
    String pretty = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objectNode);
    return objectNode.toString().replace("\"", "\\\"");
}
```

**Update Solution:** As mentioned in comment, the root cause that the service was not able to process my state string is not due to string escape, but due to incorrect attribute name (which is further converted to json key String).

Comment: `"{\"playing\": false}"` is not JSON. You are looking for the wrong thing here.

Comment: what tag are you suggesting? But my solution is based on jackson objectMapper.convertValue.

Comment: It might be that some debugging console displays the string `{"playing": false}` as `"{\"playing\": false}"` (note the extra double quotes on the outside). That does not mean that the string is broken. It means that the debugging console adds backslash escaping so the string is valid in Java when you copy and paste it. I think that is what you are seeing here.

Comment: I might forget to mention that I send this state string to server, and my server is not able to process `{"playing": false}`, but able to process `"{\"playing\": false}"`. I will update my question for this clarification.

Comment: No, the server is able to process `{"playing": false}`. Trust me.

Comment: Actually I tried. I think there might be some processing happened at the server side. Unfortunately I am not able to further debug from server side.

Comment: Well, hard to say. I suggest you try sending the data with a different tool first in order to find out what the server really accepts. Either way, adding backslashes to a JSON string is not the solution you should be trying, that's pointless.

Comment: @Tomalak, you are right - I found my root cause is due to incorrect attribute name in class which is further converted to Json key String. String escape is not a problem.

Comment: Good for you! Thanks for the feedback as well, much appreciated. :)